# Compute cummulative sum until a zero appears

Tags: python, list

I have a (long) list in which zeros and ones appear at random:

`list1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

1.I want to get another list

- the sum of the list up to where 0 appears
- where 0 appears, retain 0 in the list

`list2 = [3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3]`

It should work for corner cases as well like zeroes at start or end
`list1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`
`list2 = [0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0]`

Comment: What did you try so far? Stackoverflow is not a place where people do stuff for you, we help each other based on what we have already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

out = []
for v, g in groupby(list1):
    if v:
        out.append(sum(g))
    else:
        out.extend(g)  # or out.append(0) if you want to keep only single zero

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3]
```

---

For `list1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]` it prints:

```
[0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the plain-vanilla way without importing anything, you could do:

```
list2 = [1] if list1[0] else [0]    # Initialise
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[i] and list1[i-1]:
        list2[-1] += 1
    elif list1[i]:
        list2.append(1)
    elif list1[i-1]:
        list2.append(0)
```

For

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

this gives:

```
[3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3]
[0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3]
[3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

respectively.